# oracle database login information

Tags: oracle, security

In a database there is a username called u1, someone tried to access u1 but due to wrong password it got locked. How to find who did this suspicious activity.

Comment: Do you have auditing enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about connection in listener.log
Location is under $ORACLE_HOME/diag/ or $ORACLE_HOME/network/log

Comment: +1 but how canI find the sessions that do the wrong login?

Answer (score 1):

IF you really want to know who locked the account you should turn on auditing for failed connections. The listener.log file will show connections, it won't show which connections failed.